# Call the logout api when browser or tab close in Angular

Tags: angular, logout

I have the scenario to call logout api when closing the angular application tab or entire browser.I tried the method

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  doSomething($event: any) {
    this.logout();
  }
```

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
};
```

I have tried these methods but seems not to be working.

Comment: ``` 
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  doSomething($event: any) {
    this.logout();
  }```

The above method is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the above event on a mobile device? If so, it will not fire if the user changes apps. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event.

The recommended events to use would be either visibilitychange or pagehide events.
Refer to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Halil, Let me try this and let you know.